# teradata - encountering error 3526 with COUNT and group by

Tags: sql, teradata

I believe that I'm encountering an error regarding the Count, but i'm not necessarily sure how to remedy this. In this instance, our "SE" table contains unique values where Equipment does not repeat. in our "WO" table,  EquipmentCode will repeat as multiple 'CR's can be present per ID. My initial idea was to create a count value that expressed how many times the equipment appeared in our "WO" table with the where clauses.

```
SELECT
        SE.EquipmentSurfaceAssetBK AS Field,
        SE.ParentEquipmentCodeBK AS "Parent",
        SE.EquipmentCodeBK AS Equipment,
        SE.EquipmentDescription AS Description,
        SE.EquipmentClassBK AS "Class",
        SE.EquipmentCostCode AS "Cost Code",
        SE.EquipmentCriticality AS Criticality,
        SE.EquipmentStatus AS Status,
        COUNT(WO.WorkOrderEquipmentCodeBK) AS "Corrective Repairs"
        FROM    IDW_PL_Surface.DIMWorkOrder WO JOIN IDW_PL_Surface.DIMSurfaceEquipment SE
        ON WO.WorkOrderEquipmentCodeBK = SE.EquipmentCodeBK
WHERE WO.WorkOrderJobType = 'CR'
AND Status not in ('D')
AND WO.WorkOrderStatus not in ('CANC','REJ')
Group By Field, "Parent", Equipment, Description, "Class", "Cost Code", Criticality, Status, "Corrective Repairs"
```

Comment: I am not sure,but in the GROUP BY the  "Corrective Repairs" looks very suspicious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove   "Corrective Repairs" column from group by statement:

```
SELECT
        SE.EquipmentSurfaceAssetBK AS Field,
        SE.ParentEquipmentCodeBK AS "Parent",
        SE.EquipmentCodeBK AS Equipment,
        SE.EquipmentDescription AS Description,
        SE.EquipmentClassBK AS "Class",
        SE.EquipmentCostCode AS "Cost Code",
        SE.EquipmentCriticality AS Criticality,
        SE.EquipmentStatus AS Status,
        COUNT(WO.WorkOrderEquipmentCodeBK) AS "Corrective Repairs"
        FROM    IDW_PL_Surface.DIMWorkOrder WO JOIN IDW_PL_Surface.DIMSurfaceEquipment SE
        ON WO.WorkOrderEquipmentCodeBK = SE.EquipmentCodeBK
WHERE WO.WorkOrderJobType = 'CR'
AND Status not in ('D')
AND WO.WorkOrderStatus not in ('CANC','REJ')
Group By Field, "Parent", Equipment, Description, "Class", "Cost Code", Criticality, Status
```

because when you group by, it only should be includes the columns that you want to calculate the aggregation function based on them and you don't need to include the aggregation column ( in your case count())

Comment: Thank you, would you be able to let me know why i'm dropping it for future reference?

Comment: you are welcome , answered you inside my answer